# How to write this more succinctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a construction in RoR that would allow me to write this:

```
@budget_project_amounts.detect {|attributes| attributes['id'] == 659 }.attributes['amount'] if !@budget_project_amounts.detect {|attributes| attributes['id'] == 659 }.nil?
```

more succinctly?  Without the use of a variable...

Edit: This part

```
@budget_project_amounts.detect {|attributes| attributes['id'] == 659 }
```

is irrelevant.  It could be anything.  I sometimes have a situation like this one, where I first need to check if something is nil, before being able to continue to get a value under it (in case it's not nil and I'm looking for a way to do this without having to repeat the first part completely.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What does the structure of `@budget_project_amount` look like exactly?

Comment: Doesn't really matter for my question. I'm looking for a construction that can check if x is nil and if not then continue with x (without having to write x completely) to do something else with it.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It would be easy to test.

Comment: `@budget_project_amount` how come a collection has a singular name?

Comment: I'll edit it, but as specified in the edit, the first part is irrelevant, I was looking for something to first check for nil and subsequently accessing the not nil part without having to retype it all.  I believe the solution Nicola gave does exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with short circuits, for instance (to mention your example):

```
(bp = @budget_project_amount.find { |b| b['id'] == 12 }) && bp['amount']
```

The result of the expression is either **nil** or the amount you are searching for. Less than this I cannot think of anything.

It's called [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) because if the first expression evaluates to *false*, than the second one is not evaluated, avoiding calling the method on a nil object.

Answer (score 3):

Avoiding the use of a variable... you can start by trying to eliminate the `if` condition at the end by using `try`:

```
@budget_project_amount.detect {|attributes| attributes['id'] == 659 }
                      .try(attributes).try(:[], 'amount')
```

However, just because this is less code doesn't really make it better code. The problem with your original approach and this approach is that both rely on type checking (for NilClass) to get the job done. And type checking is a code smell.

I like to get around type checking by using [Naught](https://github.com/avdi/naught). With the right null object setup you can do this instead:

```
Maybe(@budget_project_amount.detect {|attributes| attributes['id'] == 659 }).attributes[:amount].to_f
```

Basically, forget about type checking, just do what you wanted to do and make sure the end result is the type of object you're looking for (with `.to_f` or `.to_i` or whatever).

For the above example to work, I define my null objects like this:

```
require 'naught'

NullObject = Naught.build do |config|
  config.define_explicit_conversions
  config.define_implicit_conversions
  config.black_hole

  if $DEBUG
    config.traceable
  else
    config.singleton
  end
end
```

This provides explicit conversions (for `.to_f`) and is a black hole (which allows multiple methods to be called in a chain regardless of where a nil appears in that chain).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple

```
@budget_project_amount.
  select{ |x| x[:id] == 1 && x[:amount].present?}.
  map{|x| x[:amount] }.
  first
```

It will return the first `amount` or `nil`

PS I guess that ids are unique...

Answer (score 0):

You can write it compactly using the abstraction [map_detect](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/enumerable/find_yield.rb):

```
require 'facets/enumerable/map_detect'
amount = amounts.map_detect { |attrs| attrs['amount'] if attrs['id'] == 659 }
```